# How do I zip up a folder but exclude the .git subfolder

Tags: zip

I'm trying to create a zip file from a folder and I'd like to exclude the `.git` sub-folder from the resulting zip file.

I have gone to the parent folder of the one I want to zip (*called bitvolution*) and I'm doing:

```
zip -r bitvolution.zip bitvolution -x ".git"
```

But it doesn't exclude the `.git` sub-folder.

I've tried various combinations, `-x .git*`, `-x \.git/*`, `-x .git/\*`, `-x \.git/\*`. I've also tried using the full path for the exclude argument... but just didn't get there.

Comment: `-x ".git*"` worked for me.

Answer (score 386, accepted):

The correct expression is `-x '*.git*'`, so the full command should be:

```
zip -r bitvolution.zip ./bitvolution -x '*.git*'
```

An explanation from http://selfsolved.com/problems/zip-command-exclude-svn-director:

> The correct incantation is
>
> ```
> zip -9 -r --exclude=*.svn*  foo.zip [directory-to-compress]
> ```
>
> You can also add a
>   `--exclude=*.DS_Store*` to exclude the annoying Mac OS X directory display metadata files.
>
> Notice that the expression passed to `--exclude` is using the entire original relative directory path as the original string to match against. So `.svn/*` by itself doesn't work; the wildcard character in front ensures that it matches `.svn` directories anywhere in the directory tree.

Comment: I had to wrap the glob in quotes or escape the asterisks with backslashes, like `zip --exclude '*.git*' -r directory.zip directory` or `zip --exclude \*.git\* -r directory.zip directory`

Comment: If you're worried about losing other files called something.gitwhatever, you can also use `--exclude /.git*`.

Comment: in ZSH I had to add a backslash: `-x \*.git\*`

Comment: My preferred alternative to backslashes and quotes in zsh: `noglob zip -r out.zip someFolder -x *someExcludedFolder*`

Comment: How to use it with tar? Its not working with tar command.

Comment: whats the -9 for?

Comment: Most of these seem that they will ignore your `.gitignore` files as well.  I'd recommend  using `'*/.git/*'` instead, as it is way less permissive, or the `git archive` approach that others have mentioned.

Comment: how do I include more than one folder in the exclusions list?

Comment: @DmitrySandalov u need backslashes coz u dont put it in quotes

Answer (score 202):

If you're trying to zip up a project which is stored in Git, use the `git archive` command. From within the source directory:

```
git archive -o bitvolution.zip HEAD
```

You can use any commit or tag ID instead of `HEAD` to archive the project at a certain point.

If you want to add a prefix (e.g., a top level folder) to every file:

```
git archive -o bitvolution.zip --prefix=bitvolution/ HEAD
```

You can also adjust the compression level between 0 (no compression) and 9 (maximum compression) inclusive, for example

```
git archive -o bitvolution.zip -9 HEAD
```

For other options, see the help page (`git help archive`).

Comment: Not only will this not include the git folder but also anything that is in the gitignore file will be excluded as well. You sir get an upvote.

Comment: Just what I was looking to do!

Comment: I'm late to the party but this absolutely blew me away. Great answer!

Comment: i wonder why isn't this the best answer

Comment: for me this was the greatest TIL today...

Comment: This is the recommended approach. Note, however, that it only archives what has been committed into the repository, and ignores any changes to the working copy that have not been commit.

Comment: Does this recursively include initialized submodules?

Comment: great answer but it does not show how to omit files, which is what I want.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't capture submodules, but there's a few solutions for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482544/how-can-i-use-git-archive-to-include-submodules-from-a-bare-repository :-)

Comment: To answer the above commenter, the reason this is not marked as the best answer is because Stackoverflow gives the wrong person the power to decide what is the best answer .. the asker.

Answer (score 35):

I added backslash:

```
zip -r bitvolution.zip bitvolution -x \*.git\*
```

man page about backslash:

> The backslash avoids the shell filename substitution, so that the name
>   matching is performed by zip at all directory levels.

Comment: prepending asterisks with slash forks for me on Ubuntu 14.04 to exclude directories

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you have git installed on the machine you are doing this, you can also use git itself to create your archive.

```
git archive --format=zip HEAD -o bitvolution.zip
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the following format if you want to ignore an entire folder.

For example, to ignore every `node_modules` folder, in every endpoint:

```
zip -r API.zip API/* -x */node_modules/*
```

Comment: Very good answer!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using zsh, command should look like:

```
zip -r target_name.zip source_dir -x '/*.git/*'
```

If you use: `zip -r target_name.zip source_dir -x /*.git/*`.
without 'regex', zsh will process before zip run. You will get error message:

```
zsh: no matches found: /*.git/*
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what worked for me using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

Comment: I did not understand how this pattern works, but worked for me at zsh.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of what I use to remove the .git folder and .DS_Store files found on MacOS and build folders:

```
zip -r workspace.zip workspace -x '*/.git/*' -x '*/.DS_Store' -x '*/build/*'
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is to use find , then exclude with grep -v

```
find . -type f|grep -v "*.git"|grep -v "node_modules"| zip myFIle.zip -@
```

looks easier for me, you might grep -v other strings you wan't to avoid.
And if you're on windows , use busybox...