# Excludes specific files from all subdirectories when creating a zip file

Tags: directory, zip

I want to exclude all .zip files in all subdirectories of the parent folder I'm zipping but I doesn't work. I have check the `man zip` pages, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28476/how-do-i-zip-up-a-folder-but-exclude-the-git-subfolder) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371579/how-to-exclude-directories-and-file-zipping-a-directory) questions without success.

I have tried:

```
zip -q -r FILE.zip * -x \*.zip
zip -q -r FILE.zip * -x\*.zip
zip -q -r FILE.zip * -x */\.zip
zip -q -r FILE.zip * -x \*.zip
zip -q -r FILE.zip * -x \*.zip\*
zip -q -r FILE.zip * -x*.zip
```

and I still get all zip files included (except the one in the parent folder generated with this command before).

EDIT: The problem was that I already had a FILE.zip in the folder which included some zip files. The `zip` command **updates** instead of **creates** a new compressed file if the file it attempts to create already exist, even if you don't indicate the -u option.

Comment: the first command is working for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the exclude pattern, as you already tried to do; The first one should actually work, even if there is a "nicer" solution.

But let's look at a simplified example to work with; I Created some directories with files with `.foo` and `.bar` extensions:

Here I run `find` to list my test directory - it shows all files and directories:

```
$ find
.
./1.bar
./1.foo
./sub1
./sub1/sub2
./sub1/sub2/1.bar
./sub1/sub2/1.foo
./sub1/1.foo
./sub1/1.bar
```

Now, we can just see what works
(we get the output file out of the way, its not relevant to the matching).

Packing all files:

```
$ zip -r /tmp/out.zip *          
  adding: 1.bar (stored 0%)
  adding: 1.foo (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/ (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/sub2/ (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/sub2/1.bar (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/sub2/1.foo (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/1.foo (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/1.bar (stored 0%)
```

Packing excluding `.foo` files:

```
$ rm /tmp/out.zip
$ zip -r /tmp/out.zip * -x '*.foo'
  adding: 1.bar (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/ (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/sub2/ (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/sub2/1.bar (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/1.bar (stored 0%)
```

Works!
Trying again with your first pattern:

```
$ rm /tmp/out.zip
$ zip -r /tmp/out.zip * -x \*.foo 
  adding: 1.bar (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/ (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/sub2/ (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/sub2/1.bar (stored 0%)
  adding: sub1/1.bar (stored 0%)
```

Works too!

So... take a close look at what you really did run there.

First you could remove the `-q` option for "quiet", hiding the standard messages shown in my examples.
As a next step, add the `-v` option for "verbose", to see more details - maybe too many, but maybe you can spot something interesting.

---

From the comments I see that removing the `-q` already helped;

The underlying problem was that the zip command used for testing was modified by the existence of the output file.
Technically, it had modified itself even...

From [`man zip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/zip.1.html):

```
Command format.  The basic command format is

               zip options archive inpath inpath ...

        where archive is a new or existing zip archive and inpath is a directory or
        file path optionally including wildcards.  When given the name of an exist‐
        ing zip archive, zip will replace identically named entries in the zip  ar‐
        chive (matching the relative names as stored in the archive) or add entries
        for new names.
```

Comment: Thank you Volker for your effort. The commands work for new zip files created with the `zip` command but not for the zip files I have in my folder, which were not created with `zip` command. That is weird!!

Comment: Do you see something useful if you remove the `-q` option ("quiet")? Or even add the `-v` ("verbose") option?

Comment: Ok, that helped a lot. Because I was trying many consecutive times, I already had a file named FILE.zip. So, even though I did not add the `-u` option, the process was indeed **updating** the files instead of **adding** them (didn't know that!). That's a weird thing. I could realize that by eliminating the `-q` option. Now it worked. Thank you Volker!

Comment: From `man zip`: _"When given the name of an existing zip archive, zip will replace identically named entries in the zip archive (matching the relative names as stored in the archive) or add  entries for new names."_ Now I know this.

Comment: Hey, that's good! And yes, the "update"- thing is odd; I added the `rm` lines because of that. Linux programs try to avoid doing things "by themselves" - but `zip` is more or less the same as it was in Windows, and DOS ;) (You can accept the answer with the tick mark, if it helped)